# How to create combination between family members from one table

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, self-join

I have one table with 4 columns.  The first column contains Group_ID. The 2nd column contains the Contact_ID.  Columns 3 and 4 contain First Name and Relationship (respectively).  I would like to show all the combinations possible for each group of families(Group ID).

| Group_ID | Contact_ID | F_Name | Relationship |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 426281 | 928562 | Jim | Father |
| 426281 | 876931 | Meg | Mother |
| 426281 | 474931 | Tom | Son |
| 426281 | 019321 | Pam | Daughter |

The desired output:

| Contact_ID | Relation_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 928562 | 876931 (Jim is Husband to Meg) |
| 928562 | 474931 (Jim is Father to Tom) |
| 928562 | 019321 (Jim is Father to Meg) |
| 876931 | 928562 (Meg is Wife to Jim) |
| 876931 | 474931 (Meg is Mother to Tom) |
| 876931 | 019321 (Meg is Mother to Pam) |
| 474931 | 928562 (Tom is son to Jim) |
| 474931 | 876931 (Tom is son to Meg) |
| 474931 | 019321 (Tom is brother to Pam) |
| 019321 | 928562 (Pam is daughter to Jim) |
| 019321 | 876931 (Pam is daughter to Meg) |
| 019321 | 474931 (Pam is sister to Tom) |

The original table contains a few 1000 records with many families (Group_IDs).

How do I create the initial SQL to set up the results in a way that I can then loop through the data?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, that’s a self-join, that brings all other contacts in the same group:

```
select t1.contact_id, t2.contact_id as relation_id
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2
    on  t1.group_id    = t2.group_id
    and t1.contact_id != t2.contact_id
order by t1.contact_id, t2.contact_id
```